# Exclude 'mirrored' rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to migrate an old dirty 'friendship' table to a new one, but I have a problem with the transition of its data.

The old table is `hotlist` :

```
id int(11) AI PK 
id_user int(11) 
id_friend int(11) 
accepted enum('0','1','2','3','9') 
date_sent timestamp 
date_accepted timestamp 
rejected tinyint(1)
```

The new one I'm migrating to is `friends`:

```
user1 int(11) 
user2 int(11) 
status enum('0','1','2') 
date timestamp
```

The `status` column('0','1','2') of the new table indicates respectfully that the request is 'pending', 'accepted' or 'rejected'.

So I've started with the migration of the **'pending'** requests:

```
INSERT INTO friends(user1, user2, status, date)
    SELECT id_user, id_friend, '0', date_sent
    FROM hotlist
    WHERE accepted='0' AND rejected=0;
```

Ok, that was obvious.

Next, the **'rejected'** requests. As I need to count them, I simply transferred them all in the same manner:

```
INSERT INTO friends(user1, user2, status, date)
    SELECT id_user, id_friend, '2', date_sent
    FROM hotlist
    WHERE accepted='0' AND rejected=1
```

Everything's fine for this one too.

Now, my difficulty is with the **'accepted'** requests. A sample data from the old table (only the relevant parts):

```
| id_user  |  id_friend |  accepted  | ...
|    1     |     2      |      1     | ... 
|    2     |     1      |      1     | ... 
|    1     |     3      |      1     | ... 
|    3     |     1      |      1     | ...
```

As you can see every friendship row, has a 'mirrored' one for both of the users. I **DO NOT** want this "double" data in the new table. I can't see the purpose of doing this in a "request-accept/deny" friendship system, please correct me if I'm wrong.

So what I would like to transfer from the old table is **only one of the two rows** per friendship. That's how it would look like:

```
| id_user  |  id_friend |  accepted  | ...
|    1     |     2      |      1     | ... 
|    1     |     3      |      1     | ...
```

Last thing. The mirrored rows was created "artificially", when the user accepted the request, so they have `date_accepted=date_sent`. I've told myself - "hey, It's quite impossible that a "real" request is accepted at the same time he was sent" - but **that's not the case**, there is a dozen, so the following query gives me what i want, except those accepted immediately.

```
SELECT id_user, id_friend, date_accepted
    FROM hotlist
    WHERE accepted='1' AND date_sent!=date_accepted;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the id of the user with the id of the friend and switch them around so that the lowest always comes first, and then use group by to eliminate duplicates. Assuming you want the earliest date, you can apply min() to the date column.

This should work:

```
insert into friends (user1, user2, status, date)

select 
    case when id_user < id_friend then id_user else id_friend end id_user,
    case when id_user > id_friend then id_user else id_friend end id_friend,
    accepted, 
    min(date_accepted) date_accepted
from hotlist
where accepted = '1'
group by 
    case when id_user < id_friend then id_user else id_friend end,
    case when id_user > id_friend then id_user else id_friend end,
    accepted
```

This would make the user with the lower id user1 and the one with higher id user2, but seeing that you changed from a user/friend model to a user/user I would think that it might not matter which user becomes user1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it wouldn't matter which user is user1 and user2, but  after thinking again, it does. I'll adapt it for my case. Cheers